# igatools install logstream error

Tags: boost

I am building igatools logstream error, try to solve the problem through http://logstream.sourceforge.net/ download loglog, but logtream installation failed, has been studied for two weeks, still unresolved,

Error：

```
[ 47%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/igatools.dir/source/base/tensor.cpp.o
In file included from 
/usr/local/src/igatools/include/igatools/base/tensor.h:26:0,
              from /usr/local/src/igatools/source/base/tensor.cpp:21:
/usr/local/src/igatools/include/igatools/base/logstream.h: In member 
function ‘iga::LogStream& iga::LogStream::operator<<(double)’:
/usr/local/src/igatools/include/igatools/base/logstream.h:667:14: error: 
‘numeric_limits’ is not a member of ‘std’
if (!(t <= std::numeric_limits<double>::max()))
          ^~~
/usr/local/src/igatools/include/igatools/base/logstream.h:667:34: error: 
expected primary-expression before ‘double’
 if (!(t <= std::numeric_limits<double>::max()))
                              ^~~~~~
/usr/local/src/igatools/include/igatools/base/logstream.h:667:34: error: 
expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
/usr/local/src/igatools/include/igatools/base/logstream.h:668:16: error: 
expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
 stream << t;
            ^
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/igatools.dir/source/base/tensor.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/igatools.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is my system environment:

```
System：CentOS 6.7 x86_64
Cmake:3.1.0
Doxygen:1.8.1
Boost:1..64.0
Trilinos:11.6.1
GCC:6.2.0 (gcc,g++,gfortran)
Igatools:git clone https://github.com/igatoolsProject/igatools.git
```

Igatools install:

Before the installation boost1.54.0 boost report error, and finally in the boost1.54.0 on the basis of the same method used to compile and install boost1.64.0, to solve the problem of boost error, although it still shows boost1.54.0, but should not affect if Maybe, I think it is not difficult to solve

```
 [root@localhost build_igatools]# cmake ${IGATOOLS_SOURCE} \
 >    -DTrilinos_PREFIX=${TRILINOS_PREFIX} \
 >    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${IGATOOLS_PREFIX} \
 >    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/g++
  -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.2.0
  -- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.2.0
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/g++
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/g++ -- works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/gcc
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/gcc -- works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Found sed:  /bin/sed.
  -- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.6.6") 
  -- Found Doxygen: /usr/local/bin/doxygen (found suitable version "1.8.1", 
  minimum required is "1.8.1") 
  -- TRILINOS support is enabled.
  -- NURBS support is enabled.
  -- Quadruple precision support (EXPERIMENTAL) is not enabled.
  -- Multipatch features (EXPERIMENTAL) are not enabled.
  -- Hierarchical splines support (EXPERIMENTAL) is not enabled.
  -- Mesh refinement support (EXPERIMENTAL) is enabled.
  -- Serialization support (EXPERIMENTAL) is not enabled.
  -- Paraview plugin building (EXPERIMENTAL) is not enabled.
  -- XML I/O support (EXPERIMENTAL) is not enabled.
   -- VTK support (EXPERIMENTAL) is not enabled.
   -- CGAL support (EXPERIMENTAL) is not enabled.
   -- Boost version: 1.54.0
   -- Found Trilinos:  version 11.6.1.
   -- IGATOOLS build type: DEBUG
   Configuring instantiations
   -- Generating physical basis table.
  Default instantiation table was created.
  Configuring Tutorial
 -- Configured: example_06
 -- Configured: example_02
 -- Configured: example_07
 -- Configured: example_05
 -- Configured: example_08
 -- Configured: example_01
 -- Configured: example_04
 -- Configured: example_09
 -- Configured: example_03
 Configuring unit tests


 ******************************************************************
 **
 ** [1] To compile and install the library run: 
 **      make install
 **
 ** [2] To use the library it should be made visible to the loader.
 **     Add the following line to your ~/.bash_rc
 **      export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib
 **
 ** [3] To generate and install the online documentation run: 
 **      make doc
 **
 ******************************************************************


 -- Configuring done
 -- Generating done
 -- Build files have been written to: /usr/local/src/build_igatools
 [root@localhost build_igatools]#
```

When i make install on the error, suggesting that logtream error message, I tried to install logtream package, but failed

```
 [root@localhost build_igatools]# make install
 [  0%] Generating file io/writer.inst
 [  0%] Generating file base/tensor.inst
 [  2%] Generating file base/quadrature_lib.inst
 ...
 ...
 ...
 [ 43%] Generating file functions/ig_function_handler.inst
 [ 43%] Generating file functions/sub_grid_function_element.inst
 [ 45%] Generating file functions/grid_function_handler.inst
 [ 45%] Generating file functions/function_element.inst
 [ 45%] Generating file functions/sub_grid_function.inst
  Scanning dependencies of target igatools
 [ 47%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/igatools.dir/source/base/tensor.cpp.o
  In file included from 
  /usr/local/src/igatools/include/igatools/base/tensor.h:26:0,
              from /usr/local/src/igatools/source/base/tensor.cpp:21:
   /usr/local/src/igatools/include/igatools/base/logstream.h: In member 
   function ‘iga::LogStream& iga::LogStream::operator<<(double)’:
   /usr/local/src/igatools/include/igatools/base/logstream.h:667:14: error: 
   ‘numeric_limits’ is not a member of ‘std’
   if (!(t <= std::numeric_limits<double>::max()))
          ^~~
   /usr/local/src/igatools/include/igatools/base/logstream.h:667:34: error: 
   expected primary-expression before ‘double’
   if (!(t <= std::numeric_limits<double>::max()))
                              ^~~~~~
   /usr/local/src/igatools/include/igatools/base/logstream.h:667:34: error: 
   expected ‘)’ before ‘double’
   /usr/local/src/igatools/include/igatools/base/logstream.h:668:16: error: 
   expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
   stream << t;
            ^
   make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/igatools.dir/source/base/tensor.cpp.o] Error 1
   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/igatools.dir/all] Error 2
   make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Oh,my god ,help me!